# Transition component nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, transition

Is it possible to add a transition to a sidebar component in main layout (for example) that will get animated if a new route is set?

It works on my page which is loaded when a new route is loaded, but not on sidebar which is not part ob the changed part...
what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Layout / Default.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MainHeader />
    <SideBar />
    <main>
      <Nuxt />
    </main>

    <MainFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MainHeader from '../components/MainHeader.vue'
import SideBarNav from '../components/SideBar.vue'
import MainFooter from '../components/MainFooter.vue'

export default {
  name: "Default",
  components: {
    MainHeader,MainFooter,SideBarNav,
  },
}
</script>
```

SideBar.vue

```
<template>
    <aside>
        my Sidebar Stuff...
         <nuxt-link to="/somePage">
             Somepage...
         </nuxt-link>
  </aside>
</template>

export default {
  name: "SideBar",
  transition: 'sidebar',
}
```

Comment: Could you please show some code? Hard to help without.

Comment: Sorry, i added some code. So when i click on my nuxtlink a new route is pushed and i try to animate my sidebar component..